How to perform PHY loopback test on linux
I have a Linux host with sparx5 network controller and Marvell AQR113C PHY connected to the network controller. I what to check SGMII connection between MAC and PHY. To to do so I'm putting PHY into so-called system-side system loopback mode when PHY send back frames received from MAC. I've been able to put PHY into this mode by modifying it's register values over MII but how can I now send some packages to this PHY?
I've tried to use arping -I eth0 1.2.3.4 to try to send some frames to the interface but according to the ethtool -S eth0 statistics no frames was send during the test. I think that the main issue that interface state is DOWN and thus network stack do not try to send frames over this interface. But I do not understand how can I force network stack to send frames even if network state is DOWN.
